# CSS :after + z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index, pseudo-element

I'm trying to create a message box with a down pointing arrow. I want to use the :after pseudo element for the arrow to avoid extra HTML, and I want the pseudo element to inherit the box-shadow of its parent.

My attempt: http://goo.gl/LDs7N

I just can't get that pseudo element to go behind the parent. Can any of you figure out where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used `-1px` for z-index, z-index is not measured in pixels, just numbers, make it `-1` and it works as intended

Answer (score 3):

[`z-index`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index) is either `auto`, an integer or `inherit`. So use

```
z-index: -1;
```

instead of

```
z-index: -1px;
```

#### Explanation

`z-index` determines rank of the element in the order in which the rendering tree is painted. As such it isn't a size value (like `px`, `pt` or `em`), as `z-index` doesn't provide continuous values (`0.1em`, 0.09em, `0.099em`,...) but only discrete values, which are simply given as an integer:

> The order in which the rendering tree is painted onto the canvas is described in terms of stacking contexts. Stacking contexts can contain further stacking contexts. A stacking context is atomic from the point of view of its parent stacking context; boxes in other stacking contexts may not come between any of its boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Your z-index is set to `z-index: -1px;` but it should just be `z-index: -1;` and that fixed it.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ch78n/7/

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
z-index: -1px;
```

with

```
z-index: -1;
```

[See your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ch78n/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Change `z-index: -1px;` to `z-index: -1;` because z-index isn't measured in pixels. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ch78n/8/

Answer (score 1):

You can use borders to make a triangle, using transparancy. The shadow is not included, because you will get a square. This solution uses less CSS3, so is more browser compatible.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ch78n/9/

Code:

```
div:after {                        
    content: '';
    box-shadow: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 80px;
    top: 30px;

    border-color: #EC5F54 transparent transparent; 
    border-style: solid; 
    border-width: 10px 10px 0; 
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```